# How to add a table before it is referenced

Tags: tables

I have a table needs to be added. The table is big and crosses columns. So it can only be placed at the top or bottom of the page. I want the table to be shown first and then comes the reference. But even if I write the table first and then comes the paragraph referencing the table, the table is still below the reference paragraph, on the top of next page.

How can I make sure that the table comes first and then comes the reference paragraph? In which sequence should I write the content of the table and the reference paragraph? And what are the placement parameters for this table?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us more about your document setup. E.g., are you providing the option `twocolumn` to the `\documentclass` instruction (or using a document class that specifies this option automatically)? Are you using `table*` environments for the tables that occupy the full width of the text block? Incidentally, have you tried moving up the `table*`-related code to a place earlier in the tex file?

Comment: 1) move table to earlier place or 2) try add `\clearpage` before or after it.

Comment: I think you need to compile two times. First it makes the references, and it knows on wat page it is. The second time it can refer to it because it knows on what page it is. The place, I think, is not important.

Comment: two column tables always come at the earliest on the page following their position in the source, so if you want it to appear at top of page 6 at it to the source file by a paragraph that is on page 5.